# Google.com and DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I did test my google chrome extension with below code in content_scripts:

```
function test()
{
    alert("test");
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test, false);
```

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": [ "jquery-1.8.1.min.js","test.js"],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*" ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

It's okay with all webpages such as facebook or microsoft..... after page loaded, a alertbox will popup, except "Google.com" => I accessed into Google.com but there is NO alertbox. I wonder why almost pages are okay except Google.com? So, I need which DOM event to catch after Google.com loaded?

Thank you

Comment: Try to add `"https://*/*"` to your content script matches, I think Google always forwards you to a secure server

Comment: I remember seeing some information that all extensions are disabled on (at least) the Google WebStore (for security reasons). It's possible that something similar happens to google.com as well.

Comment: @Dan Lee: you're right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is always in **https**, your script is not injected to any **https** websites since you target only **http** websites (in your manifest you have: `"matches": [ "http://*/*" ],`).

Change your manifest to `"matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],` or `"matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],`.